# Android Studio AVD Emulator transparent after Windows Update

Tags: java, android, android-studio

After a recent windows update, my emulator for Android studio has gone transparent and I am unable to do anything about it. I have been using Nexus 5X to develop my app and now the screen is transparent when i try to run my app. Is there anything I can do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

After days of search i've fixed the "trasparent emulator" by just upgrading video drivers via GeForce Experience